# Read documents from all Partition in a collection from CosmosDB

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

Created a Collection in Cosmos DB with Email as partition key and added around ten documents to that collection.

[image]

When I query the collection with `Partition Key` in `RequestOptions`, returns all the documents which has the supplied partition key.

```
var result = await documentRUClient.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<string>
(UriFactory.CreateStoredProcedureUri(DataBaseId, CollectionId, 
"GetCollection"), new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = 
new PartitionKey("test @test.com") });
```

Stored Procedure:

```
function GetCollection() {
    var context = getContext();
    var collectionManager = context.getCollection();        
    var collectionLink = collectionManager.getSelfLink();

    var query = "SELECT * FROM c";

    collectionManager.queryDocuments(collectionLink, query, function(err, documents){
        context.getResponse().setBody(documents);
    });
}
```

Now I need to get all the documents from all partition in that collection. I have tried the below code, but it gives the error ***PartitionKey value must be supplied for this operation.***

```
 var result = await documentRUClient.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<string>
    (UriFactory.CreateStoredProcedureUri(DataBaseId, CollectionId, 
    "GetCollection"));
```

Please suggest a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a limitation of the Stored procedure in Cosmos. It can execute only within the partition.

Below is the extract from the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming#database-program-transactions)

> If the collection the stored procedure is registered against is a single-partition collection, then the transaction is scoped to all the documents within the collection. If the collection is partitioned, then stored procedures are executed in the transaction scope of a single partition key.

You have to use [CreateDocumentQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.createdocumentquery?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Client_DocumentClient_CreateDocumentQuery__1_System_String_System_String_Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Client_FeedOptions_) and setting the EnableCrossPartitionQuery as true in the [FeedOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.feedoptions?view=azure-dotnet) to get all the document in the collection.